# Mysql Query for getting top instances of a class

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below:

```
COL1  | COL2   | COL3
______________________
ITEM1 | CLASS1 | DATE1
ITEM2 | CLASS3 | DATE2
ITEM3 | CLASS1 | DATE3
ITEM4 | CLASS2 | DATE4
ITEM5 | CLASS1 | DATE2
ITEM6 | CLASS3 | DATE6
ITEM7 | CLASS2 | DATE3
.
.
```

I want to arrange the data by descending date and then get the top 2 entries for every class. I am unable to figure out how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query, it ranks records in a group, then uses rank to filter result -

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM (
  SELECT e1.*, COUNT(*) p FROM entries e1
    LEFT JOIN entries e2
      ON e1.col2 = e2.col2 AND e1.col3 <= e2.col3
    GROUP BY e1.col2, e1.col3
  ) t
WHERE p < 3

+-------+--------+-------+
| col1  | col2   | col3  |
+-------+--------+-------+
| ITEM5 | CLASS1 | DATE2 |
| ITEM3 | CLASS1 | DATE3 |
| ITEM7 | CLASS2 | DATE3 |
| ITEM4 | CLASS2 | DATE4 |
| ITEM2 | CLASS3 | DATE2 |
| ITEM6 | CLASS3 | DATE6 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: +1 from me as well ;) Better use this than the monstrosity i suggested ;)

Comment: @Devart This is awesome.Thank you so mush. the result I have shown comes as a join of 2 tables. but I will work it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Didnt tried, please give a try:

```
SELECT t.*, max(col3) as `date`  /* Most recent date */
  FROM table t
  GROUP BY col2 

UNION 

SELECT t2.*, max(col3) as `date` /* second recent date */
  FROM table t2
  WHERE col3 NOT IN 
     (SELECT max(col3) WHERE col2 = t2.col2 GROUP BY col2) 
  GROUP BY col2
```

Comment: second query should not have a group by?

Comment: not only the subquery, but the query itself(the query after union) should be a group by query. As it is, would return a single value. And you missed the rest of the column in the SELECT clause.

Comment: fixed, anyway, there is a better solution than this

Comment: but is valid and not very ugly. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
(
SELECT t1.* FROM the_table t1
   LEFT JOIN the_table t2 ON t2.col2=t1.col2 AND t2.col3<t1.col3
   LEFT JOIN the_Table t3 ON t3.col2=t2.col2 AND t3.col3<t2.col3
WHERE t3.col2 IS NULL AND t2.col2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.col2,t1.col3 DESC
)
UNION
(
SELECT t4.* FROM the_table t4
   LEFT JOIN the_table t5 ON t4.col2=t5.col2 AND t4.col1!=t5.col1
   LEFT JOIN the_Table t6 ON t5.col2=t6.col2 AND t5.col1!=t6.col1
WHERE t6.col1 IS NULL
ORDER BY t4.col3 DESC
)
```

Note: the second part in union is for fetching the rows that have less than 3 records per class

Comment: Better use @Devart's suggestion.